# rth adjugate matrix and determinant of a sum, in Horn

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In *Horn, matrix analysis,* 2nd edition, it is stated p.29 that

$$\det (sA+tB) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} s^kt^{n-k}\text{tr}(adj_k(A)C_r(B))$$

$adj$ is the $r-$th adjugate matrix, $C_r$ is the $r-$th compound matrix.

I don't understand what that mean, as the dimension in the product don't match.
Does this make sense using some outside product or something ?

**Definition used**

The *r-th compound matrix* of a matrix $A\in M_{m,n}$ is the $ {m \choose r}$ by $ {n \choose r}$ matrix defined by $(C_r A)_{si_k,sj_l} = det A[si_k,sj_l] $

where $si_k$ and $sj_l$ are ordered sequences in $\{1..m\}$ and $\{1..n\}$ and $[]$ denotes subindexing

The *r-th adjugate matrix* of a square matrix $A\in M_{n,n}$ is the $ {n \choose r}$ by $ {n \choose r}$ matrix defined as 
$(adj_r A)_{si_k,sj_l} = -1^{p(si_k,sj_l)} = det A[si_k^c,sj_l^c] $

with similar conventions

**PS:** Also it comes just 2 lines after a clear error, where it says that $adj_1(A) =A$ whereas is should obviously be the regular adjoint of $A$. That said the book is very good.

**Edit** I realize now it is a simple error in the book. 
It would be interesting to know what are the alternate ways to compute the determinant of the weighted sum.

Comment: I don't know the notations $adj_k$ and $C_r$; is $C_r$ something like the transpose of $adj_{n-r}$ ? That said, the $r$ makes no sense in the formula and probably should be $n-k$, but I am not sure if the formula is correct even then. (Nowadays' approach to $\det(sA+tB)$ is just to write it as a wedge product and use the latter's multilinearity.)

Comment: intesting, would you have a link for the wedge product approach ?

Comment: (for the compound matrix, it seems the same is used in wikipedia, which we all agree is the reference ;) ) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_matrix

Comment: i realize it might be too narrow a question, as this notion does not seem widespread.

Comment: It's not "too narrow"; you just should write up the definitions as the question should be independent of the book.

Comment: interesting video on wedge stuff here. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uINebibjR5I